# how do i activate my jquery accordion, it is not working?

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion

Here is my code, I am working local file of jquery. I  have been trying to add an accordion to that code but, it is not responding. I tried to put an alert to see if my JavaScript is working and I saw that it is responding, I don't know what's wrong with my code.

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3><a href="#">Web development journey</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>This how i ended up into the programming field...</p>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Early Childhood and Education</a></h3>

  <div>
    <p>I waas born somewhere in the year 1999. I was born in a small village called Masuka village in Gokwe town, Midlands province, Zimbabwe.I am the first and lastborn...</p>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Secondary and Tertiary education</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>In my grade 7, I managed to score enough marks.....
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).on('ready', function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the jQuery UI Example: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/ I created the following from your code.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3><a href="#">Web development journey</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>This how i ended up into the programming field...</p>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Early Childhood and Education</a></h3>

  <div>
    <p>I waas born somewhere in the year 1999. I was born in a small village called Masuka village in Gokwe town, Midlands province, Zimbabwe.I am the first and lastborn...</p>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Secondary and Tertiary education</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>In my grade 7, I managed to score enough marks.....
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is working as expected. Please check your code for proper syntax.